# What could cause my pc to freeze?

Tags: freeze, hardware-failure

I bought myself a new computer last month and I am experiencing a lot of (random) freezes.

**What freezes?**

The screen and pc freeze completely, I can no longer use my keyboard or mouse. The only thing left to do is pushing the power button until the computer shuts down.

**When do these freezes occur?**

1. Whenever I use my computer for basic stuff (facebook, youtube, microsoft office, windows explorer, vlc, ...), there's no way to tell when a freeze will happen. They *seem* to be random, but always occur within 15 to 20 minutes after starting windows.
2. Whenever I try to open one of my (java) projects with IntelliJ or Eclipse, the freeze occurs immediatly (while the IDE is loading the project).

**What have I tried to pinpoint the reason for the freezes?**

1. Both reinstalled and updated all drivers. => freezes keep occuring.
2. Booted in safe mode. => freezes keep occuring. => I assume this means it is not a driver problem?
3. Reinstalled OS multiple times (Windows 7, Windows 10, Ubuntu 15.04) => freezes keep occuring => I assume this means it's a hardware problem?
4. I ran a chkdsk to scan my hard-drive for errors. => no errors were found.
5. I ran memtest86 to scan my memory for errors. => no errors were found.

**Specs:**

- AMD FX-9590 Eight Core CPU (4.7GHz-5.0GHz/16MB CACHE/AM3+)
- ASUS® M5A99FX PRO R2.0 (DDR3, USB3.0, 6Gb/s,CrossFireX/SLI)
- 32GB KINGSTON HYPER-X BEAST DUAL-DDR3 2133MHz X.M.P (4 x 8GB KIT)
- 4GB NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960 - DVI, HDMI, 3 x DP - 3D Vision Ready
- 480GB KINGSTON V300 SSD, SATA 6 Gb (450MB/R, 450MB/W)
- CORSAIR 550W VS SERIES™ VS-550 POWER SUPPLY
- Corsair H80i GT Hydro Series High Performance CPU Cooler
- 2 Dell U2414h Monitors

**My question:**

Does anyone have any idea what could cause these freezes and how to solve it? What other steps could I take in pinpointing the origin of the freezes?

**Edit:**

My event logs after starting IntelliJ and immediately freezing, a push to the power button and a restart:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Anything interesting in your event logs?

Comment: No. (I should have mentioned this). The only (related) thing I could see is that windows experienced an unexptected shutdown (me pushing the power button). I don't have the logs at hand right now, but I'll edit the question asap with them if you think they might help.

Comment: Unexpected errors just before the shutdown (if there are any) would be interesting to see ...

Comment: chkdsk cheks the file system.  So just because the file system has no errors does not mean the OS isn't waiting on I/O which often are caused by failing HDDs.  I don't see where you checked the health status of the actual HDD, chkdisk, does not do that.

Comment: @DavidPostill I posted screenshots of the event logs.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks a lot for that information. I did not know that. How would you suggest checking the health status of the actual HDD?

Comment: @MaartenDhondt There's free software such as GSmartControl to check the SMART status of your drive. This will give you all the information you need for a diagnosis.

Comment: @Daedalus I am not sure exactly how to use that SMART status information. But I ran all tests GSmartControl had; and all were successful. No errors found.

Comment: Do you have an http server installed or any files accessible over the network? Check if requests continue being served after a freeze.

Comment: @Mooseman I added some shared files on my pc. I was able to access them via my laptop. When I triggered the freeze on my pc (I opened IntelliJ), my laptop was no longer able to access any shared files.